# How can i get this div to render inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I need to get a certain div inside another div, by using HTML and CSS. I placed the div `go-button` in the `initial-bar`, but won't work. Anyways, here's my code.

```css
body {
    background: #2a2a2a;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.p-title-bar {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:  32px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-style: oblique;
}
.go-button {
    background-color: #207000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="initial-bar" style="background-color: #1a1a1a; width: 1440px; height: 90px;">
    <div class="text-title-spacing">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
        <h1 class="p-title-bar">&nbsp;&nbsp;.HUS</p>
    <div class="go-button">

    </div>
</div>
```

It shows the div `go-button` out of the div `initial-bar`, How can i get the div `go-button` in the div `initial-bar`.

I tried to get it with CSS `text-align` in center, and `align` in center also. I expected the div `go-button` to be inside the div `initial-bar`. And it resulted on a green 100x50 pixels square with a `border-radius` of 10 pixels.

Comment: Do you want to center the inner div???

Comment: I want it a bit spaced away from the h1 class  `p-title-bar`

Comment: You need to close h1 with </h1> not with </p>

Comment: your html structure was disturbed. I updated in the answer. Now it is showing inside the .initial-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, your h1 is being closed with a </p> which is fixed below.  h1's are typically block elements,  change this one to inline or inline-block.  Then change the display on the go button to inline-block.

That said, will solve your problem but a better way (IMO) is to use flexbox

```css
body {
    background: pink;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.p-title-bar {
    color: red;
    font-size:  32px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-style: oblique;    
    display:inline-block;
}
.go-button {
    background-color: #207000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="initial-bar" style="background-color: lightgreen; width: 1440px; height: 90px;">
    <div class="text-title-spacing">
        &nbsp 
    </div>
        <h1 class="p-title-bar">&nbsp;&nbsp;.HUS</h1>
    <div class="go-button">

    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
}

.p-title-bar {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-style: oblique;
  
}

.go-button {
  background-color: #207000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  
}

.initial-bar{
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;}
```

```html
<div class="initial-bar" style="background-color: lightgreen;  height: 90px;">
  
  <div class="text-title-spacing">
    &nbsp
  </div>
  
  <h1 class="p-title-bar">&nbsp;&nbsp;.HUS</h1>
  
  <div class="go-button">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your html structure is disturbing because you are have closing p tag with for h1 tag. Here is the updated code:-

```css
  body {
            background: #2a2a2a;
            color: white;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        .p-title-bar {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-size:  32px;
            line-height: 18px;
            font-style: oblique;
        }
        .go-button {
            background-color: #207000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="initial-bar" style="background-color: #1a1a1a; width: 1440px; height: 90px;">
        <div class="text-title-spacing">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <h1 class="p-title-bar">&nbsp;&nbsp;.HUS</h1>
        <div class="go-button">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is an error because you open an `<h1>` tag and close it with `<p>`

which generates that a `<p>` element is created and this moves the `<div>` below

I don't know if this solves your problem because I don't quite understand what result you want to achieve